# jquery plugin for displaying Facebook Comments with Graph API

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, facebook-graph-api

I am building a snippet to get the Facebook comments with graph API & display them in my div.

Right now, I am passing the comments count as a parameter to function. I want to make this a plugin where I can define like count: 5.

Please provide me some inputs.

```
<html>
<head><title>facebook comments</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    //FBComments Initialize - Pass Comments Count as Parameter
    fbComments.init('6');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Begin Main Wrapper -->
        <div class="fbCommentsBlock">

        <!-- Begin Question Wrapper -->
        <div class="questionPoll">
            <span>Q: Which do your kids prefer?</span>
        </div>
        <!-- End Question Wrapper -->

        <!-- Begin Comments Listing -->
        <ul class="fbComments"></ul>
        <!-- End Comments Listing -->

        <!-- Begin See More Comments Link -->
        <div class="seeMoreLinkFB">
           <a class="seemore bulletLinks" href="#">see more</a>
        </div>
        <!-- End See More Comments Link -->

        <!-- Begin Comment on Facebook Link -->
        <div class="commentsLinkFB">  
           <a class="bulletLinks" href="" target="_blank">comment on facebook</a>
        </div>
        <!-- End Comment on Facebook Link -->
        </div>
<!-- End Main Wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript function:

```
//FB Comments with Graph API
fbComments = {
    init: function(count) {
        var fbURL = 'https://www.facebook.com/lokeshyadav/';
        var questionID = 981234987242398;
        var seeMoreURL = ''+ fbURL + questionID +'';
        $('.commentsLinkFB a').attr({href:seeMoreURL, target:'_blank'});
        var fbCommentsURL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+ questionID +'/comments?limit=0';
        $.ajax({
            url: fbCommentsURL,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (obj) {
                for(var i = obj.data.length-1; i >= obj.data.length-count; i--) {
                    var userFullName = obj.data[i].from.name.split(' ');
                    var userName = userFullName[0];
                        if(userFullName.length > 1)
                        {
                            userName += ' ' + userFullName[userFullName.length -1]
                        }
                    var fbComments = '<li><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'+ obj.data[i].from.id +'/picture" alt="" class="fb_profilePic"/><p class="commentText"><span class="fbUserName">'+ userName +' says:</span><span class="fbCommentText multiline">&quot;'+ obj.data[i].message +'&quot;</span></p></li>';
                    $('.fbComments').append(fbComments);
                    $('.fbComments').css('background','none');
                }

                for (var i = obj.data.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
                    var fbAllComments = '<li><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'+ obj.data[i].from.id +'/picture" alt="" class="fbpic"/><p class="fbCommentText"> <span class="fbUserName">'+ obj.data[i].from.name +' says:</span><span>&quot;'+ obj.data[i].message +'&quot;</span></p></li>';
                    $('.fbCommentsMod').append(fbAllComments);
                    $('.fbCommentsMod').css('background','none');
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                $('.fbComments').css('background','none');          
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can I convert this into a plugin where I can call the function by providing the setting parameters like below:

```
fbComments({
    count:5, 
    seemorelink: no, 
    facebookComment: yes
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://jqueryboilerplate.com - It gives you a good template to start off.
Further it already provides solutions for handling default values and passing options.